# Add detected topics to input data

Tags: r, quanteda, tidytext

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stm)
library(janeaustenr)
library(tidytext)

library(quanteda)
testDfm <- gadarian$open.ended.response %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)  %>%
    dfm()
    
out <- convert(testDfm, to = "stm")
documents <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <- out$meta

topic_model<- stm(documents = out$documents, vocab = out$vocab, K = 5)
```

Using these lines a topic modeling approach is possible

How is it possible to use tidytext in order to receive for every row of input data gadarian see every row linkedin to which topic, adding topics to input data?

Example of expected output

```
"MetaID" "treatment" "pid_rep"  "open.ended.response" "topic_number"
```

Update code as example of expected output:

```
library(stm)
library(tidyr)
library(quanteda)
testDfm <- gadarian$open.ended.response %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)  %>%
    dfm()
    
out <- convert(testDfm, to = "stm")
documents <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <- out$meta

fittedModel <- stm(documents = out$documents, vocab = out$vocab, K = 5)

documentMatches <- findThoughts(fittedModel, texts = gadarian$open.ended.response, n = 1)
docTopics <- sapply(1:nrow(gadarian), function(docIndex) { names(documentMatches$index[documentMatches$index == docIndex][1]) })
gadarian$topic <- docTopics
```

Comment: I think there is not enough explanation about what you are trying to do

Comment: so do you want to edit the testDfm data frame?

Comment: which one is your input dataset gadarian? based on your code testDfm is single data frame but the rest are lists

Comment: fittedModel is not found

Comment: by the way, so you want to add a column in gadarian$open.ended.response?

Comment: what kind of values do you want the new column to contain? just NAs?

Comment: the gadarian$topic contains the information for the topics of only 5 rows, the rest is NA. Do you want to have the information of the corresponding topic for each row? if yes, how are the topics assigned?

Answer (score 2):

```
install.packages("reshape2")
library(reshape2)
td_beta <- tidy(fittedModel)
td_beta
td_beta %>%
  group_by(topic) %>%
  top_n(10, beta) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(term, beta)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~ topic, scales = "free") +
  coord_flip()
td_gamma <- tidy(fittedModel, matrix = "gamma",
                 document_names = rownames(gadarian))
td_gamma
```

Comment: could this be useful? it gives a word-topic and document-topic information

Comment: https://juliasilge.github.io/tidytext/reference/stm_tidiers.html

Comment: yes, I understand, you want to assign topics to the 341 rows and not all splitter, I will try to check it again